# Certain unicode hex character code causing package to freeze/hang/fail

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm currently working on a job that requires inserting records into a database, from an xml document that has a name column that contains hex character codes.

Codes such as `&#xC3; and &#xE4;`     work fine, however
the code `&#x160;` causes the job to enter a hanging state/freeze up/fail.

Why is this character code causing the job to freeze up?

Comment: What is the error message?  Is it because of the space in the code?

Comment: There isn't an exact error message, it just puts the job into a hanging state and eventually freezes up without completing the job. I've limited the problem to one record that has a string value of "BU&#x160;I" all other character codes do not cause a problem, just &#x160;